# Silverlight error-handling conventions: There is no relationship between onSilverlightError and ReportErrorToDOM()?

Tags: c#, silverlight

When I see the call `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval` (which is evil) in `ReportErrorToDOM` (in `App.xaml.cs`) this shows me that it has no relationship to `onSilverlightError`. So what kind of JavaScript-based scenario calls `onSilverlightError`? When will `onSilverlightError` definitely be needed? What are Silverlight error-handling conventions in general?

This is a very important comment by [Erik Monk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963750/handling-silverlight-onerror-callback) but needs more detail:

> There are 2 kinds of terminal errors
>   in Silverlight. 1) Managed errors (hit
>   the managed
>   Application_UnhandledException
>   method). Note that some errors may not
>   even get to this point. If the managed
>   infrastructure can't be loaded for
>   some reason (out of memory error
>   maybe...), you won't get this kind of
>   error. Still, if you can get it, you
>   can use a web service (or the CLOG
>   project) to communicate it back to the
>   server. 2) Javascript errors.

Comment: When you instantiate a Silverlight plug-in on a Web page, you have the option to use the JavaScript helper file Silverlight.js. The Silverlight.js file also provides a default event handler for the OnError handler parameter. When you leave the onError parameter in a CreateObject call unspecified or null (using the Silverlight.js functions), the default handler function defined in Silverlight.js is invoked when native script errors are encountered.

Comment: The default OnError event-handler function defined in Silverlight.js displays a dialog box for many errors. You probably do not want to deploy production code or Web sites with this behavior. OnError is used and will be invoked for many asynchronous errors that cannot be fully eliminated from a real-time, real-world deployment of a Silverlight-based application.

Comment: If a synchronous method call fails and the method call is in a try/catch block, an error object, described in "ECMAScript Language Specification" (ECMA-262), is passed to the catch block and an onError event is not raised. Because an onError event is not raised, the onError event handler is not called. If a synchronous method call fails and the method call is not inside a try/catch block, an onError event is raised and routed to the onError handler of the Silverlight plug-in. The ErrorType in the event arguments sent to the onError handler is set to RuntimeError.

Comment: I recommend you change how you're instantiating the Silverlight control. Instead of using the object tag, you can call Silverlight.CreateObjectEx() in the Silverlight.js file. This is probably a little more natural for your scenario. If it fails, you can call it again which is simpler than trying to reload object tags. ---Eric Mork (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963750/handling-silverlight-onerror-callback)

Comment: @rasx:  Rather than dumping all this extra info in a series of comment which have a limited size and limited formating features, consider moving it all into the question itself.  It would make all this much easier to read.

Comment: Silverlight.js depends on browser implementation details that can change between Silverlight releases. For this reason, the use of Silverlight.js is not recommended. However, if you choose to use Silverlight.js, you should periodically check for an updated version from the Silverlight.js page of the MSDN Code Gallery. ---MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I will seriously cut back on answering my own questions in public but the one detail that needed was setting `param name="source"` to some bogus value. Once I did this the `onSilverlightError` event fired---thus explaining to me why it is needed. Sorry, again...